# How to change the color of List of Figures' page numbering?

Tags: table-of-contents, color, page-numbering, article

I am trying to make a dark theme LaTex PDF because it would look awesome but I came across a problem: the color of page numbering for List of Figures is not changing no matter how hard I try. Here's the screenshot:

[image]

Everything worked perfectly even the dotted lines, but the page numbering on the right just won't budge. The page numbering for Table of Contents is working great and so I have no idea what's wrong.

I am using `article` class and I don't have any toc or tof package except for `fancyhdr` and `caption`.

I tried putting `\textcolor` in every single place where I can put inside/outside the `\listoffigures` and I tried using `tocloft` package but I'm not quite sure how to do that... I have also tried using `\addtocontents` and `\captionsteup` but it just won't change the color.

I'm not very good at LaTeX so I might be doing something wrong here if anyone could show me how that will be awesome.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) I guess this is related to the `\normalcolor` used in style for page number in `\@dottedtocline` and some other places. Can you provide a complete example, also called [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: Sorry but I think that your example is awful, not awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change the color for the text in the preamble. Then the color of `\normalcolor` (used by eg. page numbers in ToC, LoT etc.) is changed too.

Example:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\pagecolor{black}
\color{white}

\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to change the color of the text inside the document and `\normalcolor` should be changed to the same color, then load package `normalcolor` and use `\resetnormalcolor`.

Example:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{normalcolor}

\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\begin{document}

\pagecolor{black}
\color{white}
\resetnormalcolor

\tableofcontents
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

The result is the same as above.

Comment: That works! Thank you :D